# How to create a Unbounded task flow in Oracle Maf

Tags: oracle-adf-mobile, oracle-maf

When we create a task flow from maf-features.xml , only bounded task flow is created . How should we create a unbounded task flow so that it could go back to the parent task flow. And also what is the use of the adfc-mobile-config.xml unbounded task flow created automatically when we create the MAF application.

Comment: I should use the task flow return to go back to the parent task flow.

Comment: From the MAF doc [link](http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/maf210/mobile/develop/maf-ui-get-started.htm#CIHDHCDA) , it states that there is no exit point in a bounded task flow, i thought that we cannot return to the parent task flow. I was wrong and we should use "task flow return" to go back to the calling task flow.

Comment: correct. Use a Task Flow return o return to the *calling* task flow - this can be bounded or unbounded. Treat a Bounded Task Flow like a module/subroutine/function call ( which it is) and so you can pass params in and out and return to the caller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/maf210/mobile/develop/maf-ui-get-started.htm#ADFMF338): A MAF AMX application feature always contains one unbounded task flow, which provides one or more entry points to that application feature. An entry point is represented by a view activity. By default, the source file for the unbounded task flow is the adfc-mobile-config.xml file.
Consider using an unbounded task flow if the following applies:

■ There is no need for the task flow to be called by another task flow.

■ The MAF AMX application feature has multiple points of entry.

■ There is no need for a specifically designated activity to run first in the task flow (default activity).

An unbounded task flow can call a bounded task flow, but cannot be called by another task flow.

Unbounded Task Flows are there to allow you to navigate to an AMX page and then usually you will call a bounded task flow from there to do more detailed work.

I do not understand what you mean by: "so that it could go back to the parent task flow"
Unbounded task flows cannot be called so not sure what you mean by a "parent" in this context.
If you need to navigate back to content that resides on an unbounded task flow, you could navigate using a task flow return (from the called task flow).